# Is there any efficient way to debug the kernel function of CUDA?

Tags: debugging, cuda, gpu

is there any good way the debug the kernel function when programming on GPU?

The way I use is using `printf(...)` or copy the result back to CPU and then look on them.

I find it is too time-consuming to debug.

I appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows, be sure to try [NVIDIA Parallel Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-parallel-nsight) (official debug tool from Nvidia)

Comment: I heard that Nsight is used for GPU clusters. Can I use Nsight for my own machine with one GPU?

Comment: If you want to debug your CUDA kernels on a single machine, you need to have at least 2 discrete GPUs (1 of which must be a NVIDIA one and capable of running Nsight).

Answer (score 3):

What about using a debugger?

If you are on windows you can use the VisualStudio Debugger .
If you are on linux (better) you can use cuda-gdb.

The typical way to create a proper kernel is:

first implement the straightforward algorithm for the cpu only.
then start with the simplest possible way of creating your kernel, upload/download data
and compare the result of this first simple kernel to the results of the correct cpu kernel.

Then start add complexity and create new version of the kernel.

Comment: That means we need to create a CPU counterpart for each version of the kernel?